# Laravel color picker not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I want to use color picker in my form and i have tried below code in my project but its not working. Anything wrong with the code?,

In view blade,

```
  @extends('layouts.blank')

@push('stylesheets')
<link   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap
/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-
colorpicker/2.5.1/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 @endpush

 @section('main_container')
<div class="main-content">

<!-- page content -->
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="horizontal-form">

   <h3 class="blank1">Vehicle Details</h3>

            {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal','route' => 
          'vehicles.store','method'=>'POST')) !!}
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.colorpicker').colorpicker();

 </script>
 <div class="row">
 <div id="cp2" class="input-group colorpicker colorpicker-component"> 

   <input type="text" value="#00AABB" class="form-control" /> 

  <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span> 

 </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  {{ Form::close() }}

 </div>
 </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
    @pushonce('custom-scripts')

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-
colorpicker/2.5.1/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js">
 </script>
  @endpushonce
```

I got an empty text box not showing the color.Is there any problem with including css or js files.
How can I solve this ?Can anyone help?

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is a meaningless problem description and mentions nothing about errors thrown. Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: @charlietfl,I don't know that adding css files with code correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the scripts through **@yield scripts** then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this it's worked fine!

```
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Color Picker Plugin Example</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.3.6/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.3.6/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Bootstrap Color Picker Plugin Example</h1> 
        <div id="cp2" class="input-group colorpicker-component"> 
          <input type="text" value="#00AABB" class="form-control" /> 
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#cp2').colorpicker();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make like this

```
<div class="main-content">

<!-- page content -->
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="horizontal-form">

   <h3 class="blank1">Vehicle Details</h3>

            {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal','route' => 
          'vehicles.store','method'=>'POST')) !!}
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#cp2').colorpicker();

 </script>
 <div class="row">
 <div id="cp2" class="input-group  colorpicker-component"> 

   <input type="text" value="#00AABB" class="colorpicker form-control" /> 

  <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span> 

 </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  {{ Form::close() }}

 </div>
 </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js">
 </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-
colorpicker/2.5.1/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you tell me anything show in console and i updated my answer and you can check this link https://github.com/farbelous/bootstrap-colorpicker/blob/master/index.html

Comment: It's not showing errors in my console ,But not get working

Comment: change colorpicker class to textbox not div tag.I updated my answer

Comment: Did you mean without @pushonce('scripts')

Comment: put like this <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#cp2').colorpicker();

 </script>

Comment: I've changed it,Not working,It doesn't take the colorpicker css classes,bcas it's not showing the element's css.So In laravel how 'ld include my css files,Is mine the correct one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158213/discussion-between-jinesh-and-saranya).